# OnClick in fragment without creating tons of onclicklisteners

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

How can I handle an OnClick method in a fragment without making a ton of onclick listeners for each button and then having a huge switch statement for them. For example, I have 10 checkboxes in my layout and I want the fragment to handle them all in the same way (have the same OnClick)

Comment: Well if the case is with checkboxes ,checkout RadioGroups that have RadioButton.Is pretty much the same but you can only check one of them.If you need to check more of them, you will need to create listeners whatsoever.Even if you create a widget that has a listener inside,practically you still created "tons" of listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy. Just do it like this if you want to handle them same way;

```
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"asdasd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        item1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        item2.setOnClickListener(listener);
        item3.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is ambigue. It is not 100% clear what you want to know.

If I understand correctly you do not want 10 seperate listeners, but only 1.

Then you get:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button button01;
    private Button button02;
    private Button button03;
    private Button button04;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
        button03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button03);
        button04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button04);

        button01.setOnClickListener(this);
        button02.setOnClickListener(this);
        button03.setOnClickListener(this);
        button04.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == button01) {
            // button01 clicked
        } else if (view == button02) {
            // button02 clicked
        } else if (view == button03) {
            // button03 clicked
        } else if (view == button04) {
            // button4 clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, sorry I'm new to android. Can you explain in a little more detail? I want my fragment to be able to handle the onclick

Comment: This is still having the Activity handle my checkboxes OnClick, whereas I want the Fragment to handle it.